# Apache Rewrite doesn't work to turn any domain name into a .com domain from a .co.uk one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using the following rule to turn any domain name into a .com domain from a .co.uk one. Why doesn't this work? Do people have a better way of doing this?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).co.uk(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule $1.com$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rules's syntax is wrong. This is the code that should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: My Apache server doesn't seem to like RewriteBase / I get the error Reloading httpd: not reloading due to configuration syntax error

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache config? Can you tail the apache error log the tell what exactly is error?

Comment: I do have mod_rewrite enabled and it works when I comment out RewriteBase. I get this RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files. I am using the Htlm5 Boilerplate.

Comment: You can comment out RewriteBase line and try rest of the code.

Comment: Just one more question :) If I wanted to change this rule so it change any domain and subdomain that wasn't a .com into a .com one, how would I go about tweaking this ? So far this rule only handles .co.uk into .com

Comment: That will be tricky if you want to capture ANY non `.com` domain in RewriteCond. It is so because domain can have 1 or 2 or 3 dots. e.g. a`site.com` oR `www.site.com` or `www.site.co.nz` etc

Comment: Ahh I see, can a rewrite rule have multiple conditions ? I could just add them in manually as needed.

Comment: We can have multiple RewriteCond lines but capturing variables will be `%1`,`%2`,`%3` etc and you will need to use all of them in your target URL like `RewriteRule ^ http://%1%2%3.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]`